# Two finger scroll on a Leaflet map in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, leaflet

I am redesigning a page for a client and they use a Leaflet map created in R, after which it was exported in .html format.
I was able to simply upload this .html file in Wordpress as a media file and then embed the map with iframe element on a page.

It all works, however, I would like to implement a behavior both on desktop and mobile devices where on desktop the map ignores the mouse scroll wheel and a user is is prompted to use ctrl+scroll to zoom the map.

On mobile devices, users should be prompted to use two fingers to pan the map.

This is the effect I am after:
[image]

I've tried adding the code below but it doesn't seem to work.
Probably because I only have .html format of the leaflet map and it's embedded as an iframe element.

```js
L.map('map', {
    dragging: !L.Browser.mobile,
    tap: !L.Browser.mobile
})
```

Any ideas how I can make it work, bearing in mind that I only have access to the .html file that the leaflet map was exported in. I could add some javascript in Wordpress but that's about it.